# Restoring OpenVZ Container Filesystem Backup

Tags: backup, filesystems, openvz

I have a server running OpenVZ -- everyday, a full filesystem backup is made to another server. However, there are no VZ container snapshots being made.

So, I have a full filesystem backup of host.example.com -- however, I need to restore a backup of guest1.example.com with OpenVZ CTID 200. Can I simply restore the /vz/root/200 directory tree from backup.example.com to host.example.com and then restart the guest1.example.com container -- or will this create issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended, but it's possible. You need to stop container and drop it's quota:

```
vzctl stop $VEID
vzquota drop $VEID
```

And then you can copy the contents, but not of a root `directory`, but of a `private`.